# COM объект из скрипта python упакованного в exe

Tags: python

Возникла необходимость создать из скрипта python com-объект. Для отладки сделал маленький скрипт по примерам из интернета и упаковал его в .exe  при помощи auto-py-to-exe. После первичной регистрации все работает, но после перезагрузки системы появляется следующая проблема: каждый раз при создании com-объекта производится повторная его регистрация, хотя сразу после написания такого не происходило. В итоге com-объект корректно не поднимается.

Если не упаковывать все это дело в .exe-файл, то работоспособность сохраняется.
Версия Python 3.7.3
Версия pypiwin32 224

Сам скрипт:

```
#!python
# -*-coding:utf8-*-  
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from win32com.client.dynamic import PyIDispatchType


class pyComTest():
    # com spec
    _public_methods_ = ['callbacktest', ]
    _public_attrs_ = ["version", ]
    _readonly_attr_ = []

    _reg_clsid_ = "{1235384F-F3F1-2341-5BA9-5FD1E58F1596}"
    _reg_progid_ = "pyComTest"
    _reg_desc_ = "pyComTest"

    def __init__(self):
        self.version = '1.0'

    def callbacktest(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, PyIDispatchType):
            win32com.client.Dispatch(obj).test('1234')
            return ''
        else:
            return ''


def main():
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(pyComTest)
    print("registred")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```